# Error with gem extension while installing Apache Thrift

Tags: ruby, makefile, rubygems, bundler, thrift

I am building and installing Apache Thrift from source. When I run make, I get the following error about Gem native. How can I deal with this gem native extension error?

```
 Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from extconf.rb:2:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/bundler20160731-25561-wpjc2k/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/bundler20160731-25561-wpjc2k/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.2.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing ruby-dev libraries. What platform you are using? Linux? Darwin?

Comment: Yes, I was. I installed ruby-dev and that fixed the error. I am on Linux.

Comment: Can you please write an answer so that a person looking for solution next time can see it?

Answer (score 0):

The program Apache Thrift requires additional dependencies some of which are not explicitly mentioned in Apache Thrift installation requirements. To fix this error, do:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

And retry. My OS is Ubuntu.